# Illustrator question. How do I cut a section out of a circle, without leaving 2 lines going to the centre

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

When I use the "Start Angle" tool to cut a circle, Illustrator draws the radius lines to the centre. I just want a space cut from the circle, without leaving a "Pacman" Shape.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Cutting a piece from the pie always leaves you with a Pacman shape, no?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the Pie Graph Tool: create a pie, select Direct Selection Tool (white arrow), select the part you don't want, hit delete.

1. Select the pie chart tool

[image: Select Pie Graph Tool]

2. Create the pie by dragging across the artboard. Enter the data you need (e.g. 60 and 40). Don't forget to click the check mark when done to commit the data.

[image: Create pie]

3. Get the Direct Selection Tool (A), select the part you don't need. Hit delete.

[image: Delete the part you don't want]

4. **Optional**: Rotate and color it. Give it a color by selecting the part and setting the fill color. Make the Stroke color blank (white box with red line). Rotate by Right-click > Transform > Rotate.

[image]

Comment: In Inkscape, I am able to choose between "Arc" and "sector". I want to do the same thing in Illustrator. Sorry if my original question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. I'm not familiar with Inkscape very much. I know hat an arc is, but what does 'sector' do if not the above?